# global.asax works on local computer but not after i publish to server

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, global-asax

How can I get my `global.asax` file to publish to our ftp site?

I have added a `global.asax` file to my project (using asp.net with c# from vs2010) which works great on my local machine. Then when I publish to our ftp site. Then copy from the ftp folder into the site folder overwriting old files. It doesn't work. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: Is the file being deployed to the server?

Comment: no only the "App_global.asax.compiled" and "App_global.asax.dll" are deployed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the "Build action" of the Global.asax file is set to "Content" in the file properties. All files set to content will be deployed.

Comment: its wierd i only get these options when i right click on the global.asax file:,
Open,
Open With...,
Exclude from project,
Cut,
Copy,
Delete,
Rename. But there are No properties or anything else

Comment: Highlight the global.asax file in the solution explorer and press ALT+ENTER to bring up the properties window for the file. Check the build action is set to content

Comment: Hi, ALT + ENTER shows only filename and the file location. I am using VS2012 website. Could you please help me how to set global.asax build action

Comment: I'm pretty sure build action is only available for web applications. This is a website

Answer (score 10):

We had to uncheck the Precompile during publishing feature in our publishing profile and that did the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found that I also had to set `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy always`

Answer (score 4):

We tried a lot of things.

1. [Global.asax is not publishing and event are not firing in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12890068/1184435)
2. [Why are the Global.asax events not firing in my ASP .NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028187/1184435)
3. [Global.asax not firing for Release build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811005/1184435)
4. [Mystery of Global.asax in ASP.NET MVC application](https://sbrakl.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/mystery-of-global-asax-in-asp-net-mvc-application/)

We also tried putting the below files in `root` and `bin` directories.

1. **App_global.asax.dll** and **App_global.asax.compiled** files
2. **PrecompiledApp.config**

None of it worked!

We had to put raw `Global.asax` instead of `pre-compiled` dll, in order to fire the global events, for our asp .net 2.0 website.

Hope this helps someone! Cheers! Happy coding! :D

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
    </handlers>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue while publishing from vs 2013 and following worked for me

yourproject-->properties-->Web-> Click on Create Virtual Directory.
(Even though you created virtual directory before try it again)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish the following files this works for me

`App_global.asax.dll`
`App_global.asax.compiled`
`PrecompiledApp.config`
`yoursite.dll`

and as @GabrielG said you have to uncheck precompile during publishing

I hope this help somebody else.