# Global.asax is not publishing and event are not firing in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am developing ASP.NET web application and for unhandled exception i am making use of 
Global.asax file Where I wrote a logic to write the error logs as

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        'Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

End Sub
```

It all works locally but when published the website global.asax not being published
still i uploaded global.asax to remote server but events are not firing 
My application uses IIS 7 as a Web server

Do i need any sort of configuration Suggest if you have any solution

Comment: can you show also what you have setup on web.config for the error handling ?

Comment: web.config is default generated by .net 4.0 .I only added Connection string and nothing else

Comment: So, what have on `<customErrors` ?

Comment: <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>

Comment: what is the version of iis on which u r publishing ?

Comment: dude , go to app pool, set the pipeline mode to classic mode and try

Comment: i already have it as a classic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i also uploaded App_global.asax.compiled and it works

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you elaborate? Where did you get the file from and where did you upload it?

Answer (score 1):

We tried a lot of things.

1. [global.asax works on local computer but not after i publish to server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3647556/1184435)
2. [Why are the Global.asax events not firing in my ASP .NET website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028187/1184435)
3. [Global.asax not firing for Release build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811005/1184435)
4. [Mystery of Global.asax in ASP.NET MVC application](https://sbrakl.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/mystery-of-global-asax-in-asp-net-mvc-application/)

We also tried putting the below files in `root` and `bin` directories.

1. **App_global.asax.dll** and **App_global.asax.compiled** files
2. **PrecompiledApp.config**

None of it worked!

We had to put raw `Global.asax` instead of `pre-compiled` dll, in order to fire the global events, for our asp .net 2.0 website.

Hope this helps someone! Cheers! Happy coding! :D