# Warm up mvc app after IIS server restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an mvc application hosted on IIS. This app requires to register some jobs when the app is starting. I implement this logic on the Application_Start event and it's working correctly.

If the IIS restarts, I have to re-register all the jobs. I tried to warm up the app with [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle) but the Application_Start is not fired.

Is it possible to trigger this event after the restart? or maybe there are other events that i can handle after the restart?

Comment: what do you mean by "register some jobs"?

Comment: I am using Quartz in order to schedule some jobs in the IIS. That's not the problem,i want to implement my logic after the IIS restart

Comment: which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Solution found [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class)

Be careful, the application pool must be set to integrated mode NOT classic.

Answer (score 0):

look in to the solution folder for PrecompiledApp.config file. If you remove that file from the published site folder, the events at **global.asax.cs** would stop firing.

hope this reference will guide you in future: [Global.asax not firing for Release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811005/global-asax-not-firing-for-release-build)

Comment: I dont want stop firing these events. I want to warm up the application after an iis restart

Comment: Exactly. I understand ur query. So look in to published folder for PrecompiledApp.config. If it is there then it should trigger the event. 